# VBA Set Column Values as Table Headers

Tags: excel, vba, import, format

I have another problem and absolutely no idea to resolve it...

I have a text file like this:

```
id:3
name:S3_SVC_HE21_SVC04
status:online
IO_group_id:1
IO_group_name:io_grp1
hardware:CG8
actual_different:no
actual_valid:yes
memory_configured:48
memory_actual:48
memory_valid:yes
cpu_count:2
cpu_socket:1
cpu_configured:6 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz
cpu_actual:6 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz
cpu_valid:yes
cpu_socket:2
cpu_configured:6 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz
cpu_actual:6 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz
cpu_valid:yes
adapter_count:3
adapter_location:1
adapter_configured:Four port 8Gb/s FC adapter
adapter_actual:Four port 8Gb/s FC adapter
adapter_valid:yes
adapter_location:0
adapter_configured:Two port 1Gb/s Ethernet adapter
adapter_actual:Two port 1Gb/s Ethernet adapter
adapter_valid:yes
adapter_location:2
adapter_configured:Four port 8Gb/s FC adapter
adapter_actual:Four port 8Gb/s FC adapter
adapter_valid:yes
ports_different:no

id:4
name:S1_SVC_HE27_SVC02
status:online
IO_group_id:1
IO_group_name:io_grp1
hardware:CG8
actual_different:no
actual_valid:yes
memory_configured:48
memory_actual:48
memory_valid:yes
cpu_count:2
cpu_socket:1
cpu_configured:6 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz
cpu_actual:6 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz
cpu_valid:yes
cpu_socket:2
cpu_configured:6 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz
cpu_actual:6 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5645 @ 2.40GHz
cpu_valid:yes
adapter_count:3
adapter_location:1
adapter_configured:Four port 8Gb/s FC adapter
adapter_actual:Four port 8Gb/s FC adapter
adapter_valid:yes
adapter_location:0
adapter_configured:Two port 1Gb/s Ethernet adapter
adapter_actual:Two port 1Gb/s Ethernet adapter
adapter_valid:yes
adapter_location:2
adapter_configured:Four port 8Gb/s FC adapter
adapter_actual:Four port 8Gb/s FC adapter
adapter_valid:yes
ports_different:no
```

I want to format it like this:

[image]

In Words:
The text file will be imported with this:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=lsnodehwf, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=":"
```

Column A will be the header of this table.
Column B has to be inserted...

Does anyone have an idea?

I don't know how to begin...
Maybe I need a better output file from the linux shell.. but don't have these skills...

Comment: 1. Paste data into Excel -> 2. Text to Columns (Split using **:**) -> 3. Copy data from 1st column -> 4. Paste on new sheet using Transpose. Follow steps 3 and 4 for next column. You don't need formula or VBA.

Comment: what...it is so simple..but I will try it with vba and transpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it - not so beautiful.

But it works :)

```
Sub transp()


Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngLastRowOfSection As Long
Dim rngFind As Range

lngRow = 1

rngname = 3
temp = 1
Do Until Cells(lngRow + 1, 1).Value = ""

    lngLastRowOfSection = Cells(lngRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    Set slcFind = Range(Cells(lngRow, 1), Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1))
    slcFind.Copy
    Set targetRange = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Cells(6, 1)

     targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


    lngRow = Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    If lngRow >= Rows.count Then Exit Do

Loop

lngRow = 1
rngname = 3
i = 7
Do Until Cells(lngRow + 1, 1).Value = ""

    lngLastRowOfSection = Cells(lngRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    Set slcFind = Range(Cells(lngRow, 2), Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 2))
    slcFind.Copy
    Set targetRange = Worksheets("Tabelle2").Cells(i, 1)

     targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


    lngRow = Cells(lngLastRowOfSection, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    If lngRow >= Rows.count Then Exit Do
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you guys for your help :)

Best regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic method for doing what you wanted:

```
Sub Separate_Headers_from_Data()
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    c = ActiveCell.Column

    Dim d As String
    d = ""

    Do Until Cells(r, c) = ""
      If d = "" Then d = Cells(r, c) Else d = d & "|" & Cells(r, c)
      r = r + 1
    Loop

    Sheets.Add
    d_s = Split(d, "|")

    For X = 0 To UBound(d_s)
    Cells(1, X + 1) = Split(d_s(X), ":")(0)
    Cells(2, X + 1) = Split(d_s(X), ":")(1)
    Next X
    MsgBox "Done..."
End Sub
```